# google+ api login not returning email

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-signin

I have implemented javascript based google+ login in my application using the following code:

var isGPInitialzed = false;

```
function render() {
    gapi.signin.render('loginWithGoogle', {
        'callback': 'onSignIn',
        'clientid': 'the client id',
        'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
        'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schema.org/AddAction',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
    });
    isGPInitialzed = true;
}


//Google 
function onSignIn(authResult) {
    if (!isGPInitialzed) {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) { //get some user info
            gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.email);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Account/GLogin',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            email: response.email,
                            name: response.name,
                            profilePicture: response.picture
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (isUserLoggedIn) {
                            if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        isGPInitialzed = false;
    }
};
```

It was working fine until I created a new application from another account and replaced the client id. On successful authentication, the api is not returning the user email in the response. I have checked in the google+ account settings for the Apps and there is not setting to give acces to the email. What can be the issue?

Comment: If this is the real `clientId`, you should rather hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the scope with

```
'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still looking for the answer, try to use this:

```
 scope: 'openid profile email'
```

Answer (score 0):

based on latest update from google developers, please change the scope,

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read

This scope requests that your app be given access to:
the user's Google account email address, as well as any public, verified email addresses in the user's Google+ profile. You access the email addresses by calling people.get, which returns the emails array.
the name of the Google Apps domain, if any, that the user belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, the issue might be that you need to update `omniauth-google-oauth2` to (0.6.0)

https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/358

Google seems to have changed what gets returned by their API. The first comment in the above issue shows the structure of the hash has changed.